# Obtaining $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ via integral of Bessel function of the first kind

Tags: trigonometry, bessel-functions

How can I prove that,

$$\frac{\sin x}{x} = \int_0^{\pi/2} J_0(x\cos\theta)\cos\theta \hspace{0.11cm} \mathrm{d}\theta$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $$J_{m}\left(x\right)=\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{4^{k}k!\left(k+m\right)!}x^{2k+m}
 $$ we have, exchanging series and integral (which is permitted due to the absolute convergence), $$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}J_{0}\left(x\cos\left(\theta\right)\right)\cos\left(\theta\right)d\theta=\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{4^{k}k!^{2}}x^{2k}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2k+1}\left(\theta\right)d\theta
 $$ and the integral in the RHS is the Wallis integral which can be calculated (using Euler's Beta function) as $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2k+1}\left(\theta\right)d\theta=\frac{\left(2k\right)!!}{\left(2k+1\right)!!}=\frac{4k!^{2}}{\left(2k+1\right)!}
 $$ so finally $$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}J_{0}\left(x\cos\left(\theta\right)\right)\cos\left(\theta\right)d\theta=\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{4^{k}k!^{2}}x^{2k}\frac{4^{n}k!^{2}}{\left(2k+1\right)!}
 $$ $$=\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{\left(2k+1\right)!}x^{2k}=\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x}.
 $$

Comment: When I use Beta function for Wallis function I go until the integral is equal to $\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\Gamma({k+1})}{\Gamma({k+3/2})}$. How do you get that double factorial solution for Wallis integral?

Comment: @Shibli The relation between the Gamma function and the double factorial is the equation $(2)$ of http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html. For prove it, you have only to iterate the property of Gamma function $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$, then use $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$ and finally extract $1/2$ from every factors.

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$J_0(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(n!)^2}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n}$$
So
$$\eqalign{
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}J_0(x\cos\theta)\cos\theta\,d\theta&=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(n!)^24^n}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n+1}\theta\,d\theta\cr
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(n!)^24^n}\cdot \frac{(2^nn!)^2}{(2n+1)!}\cr
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}=\frac{\sin x}{x}.
}
$$
**Edit:** Note that
$$\eqalign{I_n-I_{n-1}&= -\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n-1}\theta\sin^2\theta\,d\theta\cr
&=\left[\frac{\cos^{2n}\theta}{2n}\sin\theta \,d\theta\right]_0^{\pi/2}-\frac{1}{2n}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n+1}\theta\,d\theta
}$$
This proves that
$$I_n=\frac{2n}{2n+1} I_{n-1}=\frac{(2n)(2n-2)\cdots(2)}{(2n+1)(2n-1)\cdots (3)(1)}I_0=\frac{2^{2n}(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}$$

Comment: When I use Beta function for Wallis function I go until the integral is equal to $\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma(k+3/2)}$. Can you show how do you solve the integral explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

We may exploit the fact that $J_0$ is a very well-behaving analytic function and the integrals $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^n\theta\,d\theta$ are known. We get:

$$ \begin{eqnarray*}I(x)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}J_0(x\cos\theta)\cos(\theta)\,d\theta&=&\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k}{4^k k!^2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x^{2k}\cos^{2k+1}(\theta)\,d\theta\\&=&\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k}{4^k k!^2}\cdot\frac{2^k k!}{(2k+1)!!}\,x^{2k}\\&=&\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}\,x^{2k}\\&=&\color{red}{\frac{\sin x}{x}}.\end{eqnarray*}$$